# Table formatting in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to make a table in PHP.
All things are fine but all the rows are printed in same line.
How to print new line after each row in table? But in html there is no need to write extra code for new line why it is showing not a new line with PHP?

Here is that part of code:

```
<div class="contest-table" id="contest-table">
<table class="contest-details" id="contest-details">
<tr>
    <th>CODE</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>START</th>
    <th>END</th>
</tr>
<?php
//Show contest detials -> Contest Code|Contest Name |Start Date | End Date
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","chandan","judge");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM judge_contest ");


echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $contest_code=$row['contest_code'];
    $contest_name=$row['contest_name'];
    $contest_start_date=$row['start_date'];
    $contest_end_date=$row['end_date'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href=\"contest.php?id=$contest_code\"> $contest_code </a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href=\"contest.php?id=$contest_code\"> $contest_name </a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $contest_start_date;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $contest_end_date;
    echo "</td>";
} 
echo "</tr>";
?>

</table>

</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? If each `$row` should be a new row in the table you should include your `echo "<tr>";` and `echo "</tr>";` in the while body

Comment: oops got it thanx i should remove unnecessary echo also thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is obvious, because you have put the statement `echo "<tr>"` and `echo "</tr>"` outside the while loop. You should put these two statement into the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<tr>'
```

and

```
echo '</tr>'
```

should be inside the wile loop